# Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event: MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void) | undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
   import * as React from "react";
   import "./App.css";
   import PageTwo from "./components/PageTwo";

    export interface IPropsk {
        data?: Array<Items>;
        fetchData?(value: string): void;
    }

    export interface IState {
       isLoaded: boolean;
       hits: Array<Items>;
       value: string;
    }
    class App extends React.Component<IPropsk, IState> {
        constructor(props: IPropsk) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
        isLoaded: false,
        hits: [],
        value: ""
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }   

  fetchData = val => {
        alert(val);
  };

  handleChange(event) {
       this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }


  render() {
   return (
      <div>
        <div>
           <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange= {this.handleChange}
           <input type="button" onClick={this.fetchData("dfd")} value="Search" />
      </div>
     </div> 

    );

  }
}

 export default App;
```

In the above code example I tried to call a method(**fetchData** ) by clicking button with a paremeter.But I gives a error from following line

```
 <input type="button" onClick={this.fetchData("dfd")} value="Search" />
```

The error is

*type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event: MouseEvent) => void) | undefined'.*

Answer (score 336, accepted):

In your code `this.fetchData("dfd")` you are *calling* the function. The function returns `void`. `void` is not assignable to `onClick` which expects a function.

## Fix

Create a new function that calls fetchData e.g. `onClick={() => this.fetchData("dfd")}` .

## More Information

[This is a very common error prevented by TypeScript](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main/interpreting-errors)

Comment: <input type="button"onClick={() => this.fetchData("dfd")}  value="Search" />
I add this above line but get the the following error
Lambdas are forbidden in JSX attributes due to their rendering performance impact

Comment: You are getting that error not because of TypeScript but because of TsLint. You can tweak the Linter or change your approach.

Comment: isn't it bad to use => in render?

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga It can force unnecessary re-renders, which is why it is often avoided. See explanation here: https://jonhilton.net/typescript-and-react-forbidden-lambdas/

Comment: Just a heads up, the link is no longer valid (gets redirected).

Comment: correct - it is NOT recommended to use an anonymous function as your onClick value. The reconciliation process will always see it as a 'change'. For instance, do these objects have equality? {} === {} ? The answer will always be no.

Comment: The link in the answer is no longer valid. Here's the updated link: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main/interpreting-errors

Comment: These comments contradicting the selected and upvoted answer are confusing.

Answer (score 74):

With Functional Components, we use `React.MouseEvent` and it clears things up...

```
const clickHandler = () => {
  return (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    ...do stuff...
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 33):

You could also do something like

```
fetchData = (val: string) => (event: any) => {
  alert(val);
};
```

Alternatively, you can set a type for your `event`, such as `React.MouseEvent`. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events).

Answer (score 1):

You can just set type this way and you will get no errors

```
export interface IPropsk {
    data?: Array<Items>;
    fetchData?(): (value: string) => void;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @basarat said [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51977836/11322237), when you have something like

```js
button.onclick = thisFunction();
```

you are already calling that function.

You may want to just assign that function but not to call it, so you would write like this

```js
button.onclick = thisFunction;
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the method connected to "onClick" can ***NOT*** have **"()"** ***directly***.

You should use the **"bind"** keyword:

```
        onClick={this.fetchData.bind(this, "dfd")}
```

Of course, you could bypass it with the trick introduced in the **first** answer:

```
        onClick={() => this.fetchData("dfd")}
```