# Button onClick doesn't work with useToggle hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, onclick

There is a button that when click it toggles a value. Based on this value, the button has an icon or another icon.

Here is the code:

```
export const useToggle = (initialState = false) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  const toggle = useCallback(() => setState((state) => !state), []);
  return [state, toggle];
};


export function Sidebar({ isOpenedInitial }: SidebarProps) {
  const [isOpened, setSidebarState] = useToggle(isOpenedInitial);

  ...
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={setSidebarState}>{isOpened ? <OneIcon /> : <AnotherIcon />}</button>
  ...
  )
}
```

It works but it has a red line under onClick word which says the following:

> Type 'boolean | (() => void)' is not assignable to type
> 'MouseEventHandler | undefined'.   Type 'false' is
> not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler |
> undefined'

I've googled this message, found a question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977823/type-void-is-not-assignable-to-type-event-mouseeventhtmlinputelement?rq=1) where the accepted answer states to change from `onClick={setSidebarState}` to `onClick={() => setSidebarState}`.

The change was made, there is no warning anymore but the button doesn't work now. I click on it and nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: in your onClick, you're missing brackets: `onClick={() => setSidebarState()}`

Comment: @PradipDhakal Ive tried like that and it says: This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'boolean | (() => void)' are callable.
    Type 'false' has no call signatures.

Comment: are you using typescript?

Comment: He is using typescript

Comment: yes, it's TS @PradipDhakal

Comment: Then @jkaczmarkiewicz solution should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mark return value of useToggle as const it will infer correct type of second element of array

```
export const useToggle = (initialState = false) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  const toggle = useCallback(() => setState((state) => !state), []);
  return [state, toggle] as const;
};

export function Sidebar() {
  const [isOpened, setSidebarState] = useToggle();

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={setSidebarState}>{isOpened ? ... : ...}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, you need to explicit say that setSideBarState is a function, so you need to put setSideBarState()

Comment: you mean `onClick={setSidebarState()}` ?

Comment: Nope, onClick={() => setSidebarState()}, using arrow function.

Comment: I've tried like that and has this error message: This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'boolean | (() => void)' are callable.
    Type 'false' has no call signatures.

Comment: , wait, I'm looking for.

Comment: You need to use "useToggle" or just wanting to learn about it?