# Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

TS newbie here. I'm getting this error on the 'handleClick' property of my `<TailwindButton />` in SignUpForm.tsx :

Type '(e: React.MouseEventHandler) => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler'.
Types of parameters 'e' and 'event' are incompatible.
Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler'.
Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' provides no match for the signature '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>): void'

I'm using VSCode and I moused over onClick to get the correct type but I'm still getting the error. I've tried using `<Element>` instead of `<HTMLButtonElement>` type as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977823/type-void-is-not-assignable-to-type-event-mouseeventhtmlinputelement) and I still get the error. Please help

TailwindButton.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'

interface TailwindButtonProps {
    icon: string;
    text: string;
    handleClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>
}

const TailwindButton: React.FC<TailwindButtonProps> = ({ icon, text, handleClick }) => {
    return (
        <button className='bg-primary rounded text-white flex items-center justify-between h-full w-full
            p-2
        '
            type="submit"
            onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => handleClick(e)} 
        >
            <p>{text}</p>
            <p>
                <img src={icon} alt="forward_icon" />
            </p>
        </button>
    )
}

export default TailwindButton
```

SignUpForm.tsx:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import profileIcon from '../images/icons/profile.svg'
import forwardIcon from '../images/icons/forward.svg'
import TailwindInput from './TailwindInput'
import TailwindButton from './TailwindButton'

const SignUpForm: React.FC = () => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState<{ username: string; password: string }>({
        username: '',
        password: ''
    })

    const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setValues(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        }))

    }

    const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>) => {

    }
    return (
        <form>
            <div>
                <TailwindInput
                    startIcon={profileIcon}
                    endIcon=""
                    placeholder="Username"
                    type="text"
                    value={values.username}
                    name="username"
                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                />
            </div>

            <div className='flex justify-end'>
                <p className='h-10 w-1/2 md:w-1/3'>
                    <TailwindButton
                        icon={forwardIcon}
                        text="Next"
                        
                        handleClick={(e: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>) => handleClick(e)} //error is here
                    />
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}

export default SignUpForm
```

Answer (score 8):

Try the below change on the `onClick` event types:

```
 onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => handleClick(e)}
```

**Full code:**

```js
import React from 'react'

interface TailwindButtonProps {
    icon: string;
    text: string;
    handleClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>
}

const TailwindButton: React.FC<TailwindButtonProps> = ({ icon, text, handleClick }) => {
    return (
        <button className='bg-primary rounded text-white flex items-center justify-between h-full w-full
            p-2
        '
            type="submit"
            onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => handleClick(e)} //error is here
        >
            <p>{text}</p>
            <p>
                <img src={icon} alt="forward_icon" />
            </p>
        </button>
    )
}

export default TailwindButton
```

Comment: I tried the fix you suggested but the error is now on the instance of the button component I'm using in my form. I've updated the code in the question to reflect it. Thanks.

Comment: Why do we have to do this?