# TSX Error: Type '(e: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>'

Tags: reactjs, tsx

I have a TSX question which wasn't answered [by this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71569958/type-mouseeventhtmlbuttonelement-mouseevent-is-not-assignable-to-type-mous), which suggests something I don't want to do.

I have a component that supports `onClick     MouseEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> | undefined`

When I do `onClick={handleSelectAllCheckboxes}` with

```
const handleSelectAllCheckboxes = (e: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    alert('clicked Select All');
}
```

I get this error:

```
Type '(e: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>'.
  Types of parameters 'e' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>'.
```

There's no explanation of what the issue is. The suggestion in the thread is to do

`onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => handleClick(e)}`

but I don't want to do it. The whole point is that my `onClick` is compact, with no expansion, and that's why I provided the dedicated function. I didn't have any such problems on providing `onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}` methods, for example: I successfully defined `const handleDateKeyDown = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {..}` and there were no problems.

Comment: A typo?  Did you mean for the function argument to be of type `React.MouseEvent` instead of `React.MouseEventHandler`?

Comment: Yes that worked. THe function signature was `onClick     MouseEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> | undefined`, though, so I went by that