# Button Event Type Error in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

TS newbie here. I'm getting this error on the 'handleClick' property of my `<TailwindButton />` in SignUpForm.tsx :

Type '(e: React.MouseEventHandler) => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler'.
Types of parameters 'e' and 'event' are incompatible.
Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler'.
Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' provides no match for the signature '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>): void'

I'm using VSCode and I moused over onClick to get the correct type but I'm still getting the error. I've tried using `<Element>` instead of `<HTMLButtonElement>` type as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977823/type-void-is-not-assignable-to-type-event-mouseeventhtmlinputelement) and I still get the error. Please help

TailwindButton.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'

interface TailwindButtonProps {
    icon: string;
    text: string;
    handleClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>
}

const TailwindButton: React.FC<TailwindButtonProps> = ({ icon, text, handleClick }) => {
    return (
        <button className='bg-primary rounded text-white flex items-center justify-between h-full w-full
            p-2
        '
            type="submit"
            onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => handleClick(e)} 
        >
            <p>{text}</p>
            <p>
                <img src={icon} alt="forward_icon" />
            </p>
        </button>
    )
}

export default TailwindButton
```

SignUpForm.tsx:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import profileIcon from '../images/icons/profile.svg'
import forwardIcon from '../images/icons/forward.svg'
import TailwindInput from './TailwindInput'
import TailwindButton from './TailwindButton'

const SignUpForm: React.FC = () => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState<{ username: string; password: string }>({
        username: '',
        password: ''
    })

    const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setValues(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        }))

    }

    const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>) => {

    }
    return (
        <form>
            <div>
                <TailwindInput
                    startIcon={profileIcon}
                    endIcon=""
                    placeholder="Username"
                    type="text"
                    value={values.username}
                    name="username"
                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                />
            </div>

            <div className='flex justify-end'>
                <p className='h-10 w-1/2 md:w-1/3'>
                    <TailwindButton
                        icon={forwardIcon}
                        text="Next"
                        
                        handleClick={(e: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>) => handleClick(e)} //error is here
                    />
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}

export default SignUpForm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e` is of type `React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>` here:

```
(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => handleClick(e)
```

And you're passing it to `handleClick`, which expects an argument of type `React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>`:

```
const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>) => { }
```

As the error states, these are two different types.  If `e` is indeed the *event* type and not the *handler* type (which sounds more likely), update the declaration for `handleClick` to match:

```
const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Issue is the type of the function should be "React.MouseEventHandler" but you type the params with it.

Example:

```
const handleClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> = 
(event : React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => {
console.log('Submit button clicked!');
};
```

And you can use like this:

```
<TailwindButton
 icon={forwardIcon}
 text="Next"
 handleClick={handleClick}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

mouseEventHandler is type of "onClick", whole function. parameter is type of "React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>"

this mouseEventHandler can looks somethink like

```js
type MouseEventHandler = (event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void;
```