# Vue 3 mouse events

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some struggles with mouse events in Vue 3.
I updated my project from vue to vite, and I have mouse events errors when I'm building the app, and it's working with `npm run dev`.
So here is the error example:

> error TS2322: Type '() => void' is not assignable to type
> 'MouseEvent'.

And it's making this for almost every event used in the project.
So here is the code example:

```
<div class="filter-card" @click="addToFilter">
```

And here is the function

```
const addToFilter = () => {
          console.log('do something');
        }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Either return console.log or remove the brackets. Now you are not returning anything (or void as the error states).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event: MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void) | undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977823/type-void-is-not-assignable-to-type-event-mouseeventhtmlinputelement)

Comment: @Wimanicesir This is normal for event handlers.

Comment: It's not normal if it cannot be built and it's working locally :)\

Comment: The question is labeled with javascript but it's TS problem, isn't it? Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . There's no such problem in general. The error means that you used a function instead of event object, while it's certainly not true in this snippet.

Comment: `@click="addToFilter()"` should fix it.